# Shell script for timelapse photo stitch doesnt work

Tags: shell, unix, parameters, cygwin, imagemagick

First of all, I am fairly new to scripting and coding in general. Please be patient with my understandings.

**Little background:** 
I found two shell scripts (UNIX) online for a timelapse photo project I am working on. The script should slice a vertical strip off every image and then stitch all together to one image. Since I use Windows, I was running the scripts in cygwin.

**To my problem:**
None of the two scripts work for me. Both of them should do the same. They are just different ways to do the job. But I just cant seem to get it to work. I always get the error "event not found" (Version 1) or "Ivalid Paramteter" (Version 2). I already altered the code to fit my image resolutions and to determine the width and heigth of the slices correctly.

The scripts:

[**Version 1**](http://blog.dcclark.net/2009/05/lift-bridge-time-lapse-part-2-fun-with.html)

**Version 2:**

```
tmpdir=tmp
if [ -d "$tmpdir" ]; then
  rm -rf $tmpdir
fi
mkdir $tmpdir
height=2592
width=10
n=0
for f in *.jpg
do
  offset=$(($n*$width))
  c="$(printf "%05d" $n)"
  echo "Creating slice $tmpdir/$c.png"
  convert -crop ${width}x${height}+${offset}+0 $f $tmpdir/$c.png
  n=$(($n+1))
done

count="$(ls -1 $tmpdir | wc -l)"
echo "Joining $count slices into out.png"
montage $tmpdir/*.png -mode concatenate -tile ${count}x out.png
```

[**The error messages I get**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGJoC.jpg)

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The command uses `!` which is being interpreted by the shell.  Put in in a file instead and then try.

Comment: @devnull You mean here? "107x2385!"? I already deleted that. And then I get "invalid parameter".

Comment: Your error message indicates that you're executing the commands on the shell prompt.  Put those inside a file instead, say `time.sh` and execute by saying `bash time.sh`.  No need to delete anything, obviously, as those are parameters for the commands.

Comment: @devnull Now I get [this](http://imgur.com/QICtgqq)

Comment: @user2688514: You have wrong endline characters in the file. You have probably used a Windows editor which uses **CR** **LF** endline while Unix systems use **LF** endlines. The shell shows you unexpected character `$'\r'` which is a way how to express the **CR** character in bash (probably the shell you are using). To get error messages in English please use: `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` before running other commands.

Comment: @user2688514: I forgot that you probably do not know how to resolve the problem with endlines. Convert the file in Cygwin or other Unix-like environment using `dos2unix time2.sh`. For editing of files with **LF** endlines in Windows you can use for example [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html).